# How can I split a PDF created with beamer at each section start?

Tags: beamer, pdf

I have a very long presentation with multiple sections. I would like to automatically split the PDF at each section.

I know there is the [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) command. However using `\includeonlylecture` loses the global page and section numbering such that sections in each lecture start again with section number 1.

How can I split the PDF such that the result is equivalent to manually split the pdf after latex created it?

Comment: TeX is not really designed to produce multiple output files, you need either multiple runs or split the PDF with an external tool. I use `pdftk` when I need to split a PDF file. To get, say, the first 10 pages of `in.pdf` saved to `out.pdf` you use `pdftk in.pdf cat 1-10 output out.pdf`.

Answer (score 2):

I modified [this bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086073/1037094) to split the pdf at sections:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile=$1 # input pdf

[ -e "$infile" ] || exit 1 # Invalid args

pagenumbers=( $(pdftk "$infile" dump_data | grep  -A1 '^BookmarkLevel: 1' | grep '^BookmarkPageNumber: ' | cut -f2 -d' ' | uniq) end )

titles=($(pdftk "$infile" dump_data | grep  -B1 '^BookmarkLevel: 1' | grep '^BookmarkTitle: ' | cut -f2- -d' ' | sed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/_/g') )

for ((i=0; i < ${#pagenumbers[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
  section=$((i+1))
  section=$(printf "%02d" $section)
  a=${pagenumbers[i]} # start page number
  b=${pagenumbers[i+1]} # end page number
  [ "$b" = "end" ] || b=$[b-1]
  pdftk "$infile" cat $a-$b output "${section}"_"${titles[i]}".pdf
done
```