# Beamer - Compile each section into a separate PDF including complete Table of Contents in each file

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning, compiling

Let us suppose I have a Beamer presentation structured roughly like this:

```
Title page

Table of contents
    sec1
    sec2
    sec3
    ...

\section{sec1}
  \frametitle{frame1}
  \frametitle{frame2}
  \frametitle{frame3}
  ....

\section{sec2}
  \frametitle{frame1}
  \frametitle{frame2}
  \frametitle{frame3}
  ....

\section{sec3}
  \frametitle{frame1}
  \frametitle{frame2}
  \frametitle{frame3}
  ....
...
```

I would like to compile each single section into a separate PDF, but each PDF should include the title page and the complete table of contents.

Is that possible? How can I achieve that?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532451/how-can-i-split-a-pdf-created-with-beamer-at-each-section-start (you can repeat the title page and toc with `\AtBeginSection{...}`)

Comment: In general, I think [LaTeX does not support outputting multiple PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228) from the same source code, without compiling multiple times.